# Fan is always running Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: fan

I have recently dual-booted my PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04. I also recently upgraded to 13.10. The problem didn't change, so that is irrelevant except to the fix I suppose. While looking around, I found Psensor and decided to check my stats.I have linked to a screenshot displaying the results, since I can't post a picture. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaHAm.jpg
You can see that the fan speed has a minimum of over 850 rpm. It is my understanding that Psensor displays the minimum and maximum values that have occurred since the program was opened. Herein lies the problem. The fan does not stop or slow down. Ever. Let me know if you need any more info or if I need to run any tests that would help. I'm willing to try whatever.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of PC do you have?  For Dell machines, you might look into the "i8kutils" package.  See, e.g., [http://askubuntu.com/questions/187144/is-dell-inspiron-15r-special-edition-compatible-with-ubuntu/232125#232125]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistent High-Fan Speed Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the min/max values displayed by psensor are the min/max values which have been measured since the monitoring application is started.

You can also see that the temperature of the CPU did not varie (45-46) so that's normal that the BIOS did not change the fan speed, there is simply no reason.

The BIOS is controlling the fan speed, so if you want to stop the fan you have to look in the BIOS settings. Many BIOS only allow to change the fan speed according to temperature threshold but not stop it.

Alternatively, you can change the fan speed by software (see http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/man/fancontrol). Note that it is less reliable than the BIOS. Your particular hardware might not be perfectly supported by lm-sensor (mostly because manufacturers do not always publish specifications) and it can lead to hardware damage due to overheating.

Comment: Apologies for 2 months of inactivity. We've been trying different Linux distro's and the same problem occurs with each distro. Through a little more research, I found that it is the GPU fan that is running constantly. In a related discussion, someone said that their "graphical driver" was unstable which made the card hot. What does this mean?