# Radeon 6520G with black screen problem. Re-boot make it work

Tags: boot, 12.10, xorg

I have a HP Pavilion g7 with Ubuntu 12.10. Ever since I installed ubuntu on it the first time when I switch on the pc the screen hangs with a blank screen, but only works after second and subsequent restarting.

My display device info http://paste.ubuntu.com/1365995/

**update**: Filed a bug report with launchpad
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1080156

Answer (score 2):

You machine appears to most likely have the ATI Radeon 4250 graphics adapter based on specifications found elsewhere.  You can confirm this by running

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

If you are currently using the Radeon driver, try using the fglrx driver and vice versa.  Radeon support is pretty scratchy at the moment.  Your bug report will not go anywhere because it has been filed against xorg when it should have been filed against fglrx or the radeon driver after further testing.  Have a look at this [previous question on installing the fglrx driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver).

A black screen does not actually mean that the machine is hung.  If you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and get to a text console to install drivers and reboot safely etc, the machine is not hung.  This is an important distinction to make at this point.

Comment: My display device info http://paste.ubuntu.com/1365995/

Comment: OK, open a terminal or a console and try installing the fglrx driver module: 'sudo apt-get install fglrx'  If it installs try re-booting.

Comment: or he you could jus goto the software center>>Additional Drivers and choose ATI... drivers.

Comment: @ Rupali : I think that would install the Radeon driver, which he is already using.