# My computer will not reboot after fresh install of ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, uefi, reboot

I bought a new computer yesterday and it came with Windows 8. When installing Ubuntu, i choose the erase and install option thinking that Ubuntu would install easily like it did for my old laptop... After a successful install and following the instructions telling me to reboot to finish installation and remove installation media. It worked and my computer booted fine, however once I began installing updates via update manager and activating  additional driver {ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)} out of the following:

- Experimental AMD binary Xorg driver and kernel module ATI/AMD
  proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (**experimental**beta) ATI/AMD
  proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)

Then reboot to finish making changes I reboot and get an error (Reboot and select proper boot device)>>>>> At this point I was stuck, so I eventually reinstalled ubuntu and repeated the exacted same steps until right before i rebooted to finish making changes. However this time i used this Boot Repair tool

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair

After running the program i get a "boot successfully repaired" message. Then I try to reboot again and get the GNU Grub screen where it says would you like to boot:

normal
recovery
memorytest

Once it begins loading, you see the code moving across the screen then it pauses when it gets to  and doesnt do anything.

If someone could tell me how to fix this or get Windows 8 back soon, I'd appreciate it because like i said i just bought it yesterday and now i cant even use it.

Comment: please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

I would go back and reinstall Ubuntu again. Typically, the open source version of that driver works better. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver) for more information on the open source version of that driver. Install Ubuntu again and try the solution in the link I gave you.

Good luck!