# Ubuntu 14.04 install problem

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 and entering my password the screen freezes.

I have tried reinstalling a few times, but the same thing happens.

Any ideas?

Please help urgently.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling ubuntu desktop.

First, access tty command line by pressing on the login screen Alt+Ctrl+F1. And you'll need internet connection, which you can get in the login screen.

Reinstalling ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Last command reboots the system.

This might be a graphics driver issue as well, so if reinstalling ubuntu desktop didn't work, you could try moving onto graphics drivers. Of course it's much more lengthy process and a little more tricky. Do you know what's your graphics card ? If you dont you can find out using `sudo lshw -C video | grep product`.

I've found how-to thread on ubuntuforums about nvidia drivers: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081649
And for ati driver: [How to install Radeon Open Source Driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver)

Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

if it installed well and only crashes when entering to unity(default desktop), that's probably the issue. before entering the passw press ctrl+alt+F1 and log in. then try to install kubuntu-desktop  -> sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
it's heavy and is gonna take a while. Then restart the computer and log-in using kde instead of unity(a little button next to username).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when when your drivers are not compatible with your hardware.so u need to download the compatible ones.

1. first of all open the grub menu by clicking f6 or f7 when ur PC starts(depending on ur PC)and then open the OS in advanced-> recovery mode and then click on fail safe X mode and if it shows that you are low on graphics,cannot detect screen and devices then the problem will be mostly due to the driver.
2. Now depending on your hardware install the drivers from the internet whether its nvidia drivers or ATI etc.
3. Then go to the setting option->software and updates-> additional drivers->then selct anyone of the drivers and then click on apply changes and then restart your PC.

This will do your work if the problem is with the drivers.

for detailed description check this out (askubuntu.com/questions/141606/…) contains all the description of low graphic mode.