# i have an issue with low graphic mod at the booting, can you help me please?

Tags: drivers, ati, intel-graphics, fglrx

I am a beginner so i dont know really whats my problem i just have a hp pavillon g7 with a amd/ati graphic card, i have tried to update ubuntu from 12.04 to 14 but its still dont work. I have tried to follow instructions on thé site to install fglrx package again but i dont really understand so i ask for help hère.  Sorry for my bas english i am french

---

I have posted on a forum.org but they dont answer so i try my chance here : i have tried to do `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ati*` but that is what my computer answer me : sorry my main langage is french

`Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation :

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 hunspell-fr : Dépend: hunspell-fr-classical mais ne sera pas installé ou
                        hunspell-fr-modern mais ne sera pas installé ou
                        hunspell-fr-revised mais ne sera pas installé ou
                        hunspell-fr-comprehensive mais ne sera pas installé
 libpam-modules : Pré-Dépend: debconf (>= 0.5) mais ne sera pas installé ou
                                debconf-2.0
                  Pré-Dépend: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.1.8-1ubuntu2)
 libpam0g : Dépend: debconf (>= 0.5) mais ne sera pas installé ou
                     debconf-2.0
 libreadline6 : Dépend: readline-common mais ne sera pas installé
 libssl1.0.0 : Dépend: debconf (>= 0.5) mais ne sera pas installé ou
                        debconf-2.0
 memtest86+ : Dépend: debconf (>= 0.5) mais ne sera pas installé ou
                       debconf-2.0
 openjdk-7-jre : Dépend: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
                 Dépend: libcups2 (>= 1.4.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libx11-6 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libxext6 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libxi6 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libxrender1 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libxtst6 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libxrandr2 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libxinerama1 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Dépend: libgl1-mesa-glx ou
                          libgl1
                 Dépend: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) mais ne sera pas installé
                 Recommande: libgnome2-0 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Recommande: libgnomevfs2-0 mais ne sera pas installé
                 Recommande: libgconf2-4 mais ne sera pas installé
 openjdk-7-jre-headless : Dépend: ca-certificates-java mais ne sera pas installé
                          Dépend: tzdata-java mais ne sera pas installé
                          Dépend: libcups2 (>= 1.4.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                          Dépend: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) mais ne sera pas installé
 tar : Pré-Dépend: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8) mais ne sera pas installé
 wamerican : Dépend: debconf (>= 0.5) mais ne sera pas installé ou
                      debconf-2.0
 x11-common : Dépend: debconf (>= 0.5) mais ne sera pas installé ou
                       debconf-2.0
E: Erreur, pkgProblem::Resolve a généré des ruptures, ce qui a pu être causé par les paquets devant être gardés en l'état.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing all the fglrx stuff like other posts suggest? Your machine should run with the standard generic drivers. Once that works you can try to reinstall the fancy stuff.

Comment: No, i have installed it, the post said install fglrx, so i have done that but it doesnt Work. Do i need to delete  all data about It?  How can i do that Thanks!  Can u teach step by step?

Comment: It looks like you are doing several things at the same time. I suggest fixing the broken dependencies / installation first ([link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade) and then removing the flgrx stuff ([link]https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto). I would also check if your system really requires the proprietary drivers and first try without them. First make sure you have the proper generic drivers installed ([link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver).

Comment: OK i paste here all things i have tipped on the terminal :

Comment: I have poste up on there, i dont know how display pics tho

Answer (score -1):

OK i paste here all i have tipped on terminal : tamarin@tamarin-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Note : sélection de fglrx-driver-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-pxpress pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-updates pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-control pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-core pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-updates-core pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-amdcccle-updates pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-driver-core pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de xfree86-driver-fglrx-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de xorg-driver-fglrx-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-glx pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-control-qt2 pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-amdcccle pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-driver pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx-updates-dev pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Note : sélection de fglrx pour l'expression rationnelle « fglrx* »
Package 'fglrx-glx' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-control-qt2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xfree86-driver-fglrx-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xorg-driver-fglrx-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-pxpress' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-amdcccle-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-updates-core' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fglrx-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-core
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 3 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Après cette opération, 480 Mo d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n]
(Lecture de la base de données... 281537 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de fglrx-amdcccle (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.3) ...
Suppression de fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.3) ...
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf » (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) en mode automatique
update-alternatives: avertissement: création de /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdcccle.desktop abandonnée car le fichier associé /usr/share/fglrx/amdcccle.desktop (du groupe de liens x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) n'existe pas
update-alternatives: avertissement: création de /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdccclesu.desktop abandonnée car le fichier associé /usr/share/fglrx/amdccclesu.desktop (du groupe de liens x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) n'existe pas
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf » (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) en mode automatique
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf » (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) en mode automatique
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf » (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) en mode automatique
Suppression de fglrx-core (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.3) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/fglrx-core/unblacklist_ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GFXCORE.conf » (x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf) en mode automatique
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Traitement déclenché pour  bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Traitement déclenché pour  libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Traitement déclenché pour  initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic

tamarin@tamarin-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$  lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
tamarin@tamarin-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for tamarin:
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
       fabriquant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       ressources: irq:48 mémoire:a0000000-afffffff mémoire:c2000000-c201ffff portE/S:4000(taille=256) mémoire:c2020000-c203ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:46 mémoire:c3000000-c33fffff mémoire:b0000000-bfffffff portE/S:5000(taille=64)
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "amd-layout"
    Screen 0 "amd-screen" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "amd-device"
    Driver "fglrx"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "amd-monitor"
    Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amd-screen"
    Device "amd-device"
    Monitor "amd-monitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

﻿
Now my computer start and i can access to the desktop now but it is showing system crash error, i will take à desktop pics tho i think its not the ubuntu 14.04 real desktop but à save mode on cordialy