# How to install the open-source "radeon" driver

Tags: drivers, 16.04, 15.10, radeon, fglrx

I "Accidentally" upgraded to 16.04 from 15.10 as it would have lost support anyway in July, and now FGLRX is nowhere to be found and only one of my monitors work.

---

Currently `screenfetch` is displaying my GPU like this:

```
GPU: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)
```

It is a Sapphire R270 and should be supported by the new `radeon` driver.
I have tried to edit the xorg.conf file but it did nothing:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "radeon"
EndSection
```

The file didnt even exist to begin with so I made a new one, but as I said it did nohting.

I have searched further and found a 10-amdgpu.conf file in

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

but I am too scared to edit there anything, since I am afraid to render my system unuseable.

Comment: duh, I know that but how do I use the open-source radeon driver ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Radeon Open Source Driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver)

Comment: did that and it didnt help

Comment: Refrain from "duh"ing other people in chat. We're here to help, but we won't if you are demeaning to others.

Comment: I mean that is literally the first result in google

Comment: Okay, then edit your question saying you went through those steps and couldn't fix the issue. For all I know, you *didn't* try it.

Comment: The accepted response does not solve this issue.

Comment: @PhillipMoxley I actually didnt have to do myself anything to solve the issue, a couple of reboot fixed the reboot, if I tried something and it didnt work, I rolled everything back to the previous state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to **install** the open source drivers.
They are already installed by default.

You can check which kernel module is used by running

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

in terminal. It will show something like this

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19d3
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

`GPU: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)`
looks correct.

Comment: so could be the reason that I cant use multiple monitors and everything feels so *slow* ?

Comment: This is another question why the system works slow.

Comment: Maybe you have hyprid graphics, etc.

Comment: its a r270 in combination with a fx6300, doesnt look like a hybrid to me

Comment: I suggest asking a new question. Describe what is the problem and post there the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'`. This question has been answered and it does not help the actual issue.

Comment: problem fixed itself, no idea why (doing backups atm just in case) but it spits out `driver in use: radeon`