# Radeon driver doesn't work with supported Card

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

I have and Intel HD 4000 and ATI Raedon 8670HD hybrid GPU on my laptop.
But, the Raedon GPU is not being used.

Specification:

**OS:** Ubuntu 17.04

Graphics Card:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev ff)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

As mentioned in this Question, [How to install the open-source "radeon" driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785788/how-to-install-the-open-source-radeon-driver),
when I run the following command:

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

This is what I get:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    DeviceName: Intel(R) Graphics 4000
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

If I run `dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'`, this is the output(Part of it):

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic root=UUID=4471312f-2d43-4d02-8b4d-0b34daa74bed ro quiet splash radeon.modeset=1
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic root=UUID=4471312f-2d43-4d02-8b4d-0b34daa74bed ro quiet splash radeon.modeset=1
[    1.197192] [drm] Initialized
[    1.233433] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.237209] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    1.237210] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    1.238609] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (HAINAN 0x1002:0x6660 0x103C:0x1970 0x00).
[    1.238618] [drm] register mmio base: 0xC2000000
[    1.238619] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    1.243736] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.243737] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.247703] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    1.247705] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000080000000 - 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
[    1.247709] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=256M
[    1.247710] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[    1.247777] [drm] radeon: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.247777] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.247783] [drm] Loading hainan Microcode
```

So, it seems like Ubuntu knows about the GPU, but it isn't using it.

In `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` there exists a file named `10-amdgpu.conf` and `10-raedon.conf`.

Comment: The driver is installed and working. Which command confuses you? If you run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'`, I think you will be much more happy ;-). If you want to use the adapter, use `DRI-PRIME=1`.

Comment: That's the output: 01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev ff)
 DeviceName: Radeon HD 8670M
 Kernel driver in use: radeon
 Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

Comment: @Pilot6: I am confused by the `chrome://gpu` page, which is supposedly using the Intel GPU, and hence gives me poor performance for my GPGPU use case.

Comment: It is `DRI_PRIME=1`, not `DRI-PRIME=1`. Please add output of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to your question. Intstall `mesa-utils` if it is not installed.

Comment: And also using radeon in Chrome will not improve performance. Radeon is useful only for 3D.

Comment: @Pilot6 That fixed it :D Thank you. If you can post that as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @Pilot6 That's all right. I need to use my GPU for use in WebGl.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `radeon` driver is intalled and working.

To use it with some application run it with `DRI_PRIME=1`, e.g.

```
DRI_PRIME=1 google-chrome
```

To check which adapter is used you can run

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

to run wuth `radeon`, and

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

to run with Intel.